# substring and finding string and adding

Tags: sql, oracle

I am analysing columns which have string in it as en example

```
"
Reading short stories in English is a
REELED IN £80.00 OF WINS
Do you enjoy reading stories?

Reading short stories in English is a great way to improve your language level. 
In this section, read our short stories dat were specially written 
REELED IN £180.00 OF WINS

for English language learners. There are 
two sections, one for lower level learners (A2/B1)
 and one for higher levels (B2/C1). 
REELED IN £60.00 OF WINS

You will improve you're reading fluency and 
comprehension and develop you're vocabulary. 
Each story TEMPhas interactive exercises to help you understand and use the language."
```

I need to find how many times `Reeled` are available in the string, and this can be random. May be 3,4,5 anything. And with every `reeled` there is an amount mentioned with each reeled. I need a column which can add all this amount together. In this case,

> 80+180+60=320

If I know how many `reeled` is there every time, then I can use  `substr` and `instr` and add the values. Not sure how to do if `reeled` are there random times. Please suggest...

Answer (score 0):

At the end, that's some kind of a hierarchical query.

For sample data you posted:

```
SQL> select * From temp;

COL
--------------------------------------------------
Reading short stories in English is a
REELED IN L80.00 OF WINS
Do you enjoy reading stories?
Reading short stories in English is a great way to
 improve your language level.
In this section, read our short stories dat were s
pecially written
REELED IN L180.00 OF WINS

for English language learners. There are
two sections, one for lower level learners (A2/B1)

 and one for higher levels (B2/C1).
REELED IN L60.00 OF WINS

You will improve you're reading fluency and
comprehension and develop you're vocabulary.
Each story TEMPhas interactive exercises to help y
ou understand and use the language.
```

Setting NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS (as your decimal separator is a dot; in my *Croatian* database, it is a comma); you probably don't have to do that:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_numeric_characters = '.,';

Session altered.
```

Query uses `substr` + `instr` combination (as you already said) which extracts the numeric part between `REELED IN` and `OF WINS`, but with addition of the `connect by` clause which "loops" through the string as many times as there's the `REELED IN` substring in it.

```
SQL> select
  2    sum(substr(col, instr(col, 'REELED IN', 1, level) + 11,
  3                    instr(col, 'OF WINS', 1, level) - instr(col, 'REELED IN', 1, level) - 11
  4              )) res
  5  from temp
  6  connect by level <= regexp_count(col, 'REELED IN');

       RES
----------
       320

SQL>
```